# Angular - Sortable nested drag n' drop

Tags: javascript, angular

i'm currently working on an angular app where I want to implement a nested drag n' drop feature where it should also be possible to sort the items in the own list.

There is a great stackblitz example how to implement the nested drag n' drop which you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-demo).

So basically I made some small changes including showing the placeholder when drag and drop and moving the `<ul>` into the `cdkDrag` div.

```
<div cdkDropList
class="item-dropzone parent"
[id]="parentItemId"
[cdkDropListData]="parentItem"
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="allDropListsIds"
(cdkDropListDropped)="onDragDrop($event)">
<div cdkDrag
    [id]="item.uId"
    [cdkDragData]="item"
    [cdkDragDisabled]="dragDisabled">
    <div title="Drag this item with children"
        class="item-drag-handle"
        cdkDragHandle>
        {{item.name}}
        <i *ngIf="!dragDisabled"
            class="material-icons">
            drag_indicator
        </i>
    </div>
    <ul cdkDropList
        class="item-dropzone"
        [id]="item.uId"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedDropListsIds"
        [cdkDropListData]="item"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onDragDrop($event)">
        <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.children">
            <list-item [item]="subItem"
                [parentItem]="item"
                [connectedDropListsIds]="allDropListsIds"
                (itemDrop)="onDragDrop($event)">
            </list-item>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to make a special case when `parentItem == null` with

```
<div *ngIf="parentItem == null;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div>    
<ng-template #content>content here...</ng-template>
<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template
```

But I can't make it to work. So basically what's wrong here is that this part here:

```
<div cdkDropList
    class="item-dropzone parent"
    [id]="parentItemId"
    [cdkDropListData]="parentItem"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="allDropListsIds"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="onDragDrop($event)">
```

has always only one child if I'm not wrong.

I also made another stackblitz where I changed the code to use a template recursive instead of the component. You can find the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-demo-cuk9zp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.html)

```
<ng-template #recursiveList
               let-list>
<li *ngFor="let item of list" cdkDrag
    [id]="item.uId"
    [cdkDragData]="item"
    [cdkDragDisabled]="dragDisabled">
    <div title="Drag this item with children"
        class="item-drag-handle"
        cdkDragHandle>
        {{item.name}}
        <i *ngIf="!dragDisabled"
            class="material-icons">
            drag_indicator
        </i>
    </div>
    <ul cdkDropList
        class="item-dropzone"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedDropListsIds"
        [cdkDropListData]="item"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="onDragDrop($event)">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: parentItem.children }"></ng-container>
```

Unfortunately the drag and drop is not working here but I think from structure wise this should be fine m

Can someone help me here? I know there are some third party angular npms but I think this should be possible by just using the angular material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by handling the `cdkDropListEnterPredicate` from the `cdkDropList`. Basically I check if the element with `.cdk-drag-preview` is in the container while moving with drag n' drop and some other checks around nested children.

Comment: Missed that post. I had the same problem in did something similar. There is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337934/angular-nested-drag-and-drop-cdk-material-cdkdroplistgroup-cdkdroplist-nested/67337935#67337935